# Multiple If condition using Microsoft Access database in VB Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, if-statement

I am trying to make a banking system where the customer will only be able to deposit money IF ONLY they enter the CORRECT AccountNo & Name using Microsoft Access Databse in VB NET.

**Here are my codes:**

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection

```
Dim conn = "provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Database\Bank-Application-Database.accdb;"

    conn.ConnectionString = "provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Database\Bank-Application-Database.accdb;"

    cmdupdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB

    Dim deposit As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Current_Account] WHERE [AccountNo] and [CustomerName] = '" & accnotxt.Text & "' AND [CustomerName] = '" & nametxt.Text & "' AND [Amount] = '" & amounttxt.Text & "'", myConnection)
    deposit.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()


    If accnotxt.ToString = True And nametxt.ToString = True Then

        cmdupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE [Current_Account] SET [Amount] = '" & amounttxt.Text.ToString & " WHERE [AccountNo] AND [CustomerName] = " & accnotxt.Text.ToString & " " & nametxt.ToString & ";"
        cmdupdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox(" Successfully deposited.")
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Account Number or Name.")
```

I am able to run.However when I click to Deposit, this is the error.

**The error I got:**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Te" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Any helpers ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ToString` usage will convert the value of the `accnotxt` and `nametxt` text boxes into a text string and you're trying to compare that to `True` (i.e. `accnotxt.ToString = True`) which is of a `Boolean` data type not a `String` data type i.e. you are trying to compare text to a boolean (true or false) value.

A very basic way (that can be improved on) of doing the account number and name check would be to change your `SELECT` statement to:

```
Dim deposit As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Current_Account] WHERE [AccountNo] and [CustomerName] = '" & accnotxt.Text & "' AND [CustomerName] = '" & nametxt.Text & "'", myConnection)
```

I removed the `Amount` filter from the `WHERE` clause as I am not sure why you are doing that. You don't even use this `deposit` database command. You then execute the `deposit` SQL command and get its result: `Dim result = deposit.ExecuteScalar()`. [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) does the following:

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

You then change your account number and name check to `If result IsNot Nothing Then` instead of checking if the values of the textboxes are a particular account number and name.

In other words, if your query returns *something* and not *nothing*, then you can assume a current account exists with the `accnotxt` and `nametxt`.

Also, pay attention to @CrushSundae answer as they have highlighted other issues too.

Comment: And how do I do that? 
Sorry noob here.

Comment: Edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jonathon Ogden's answer:

You missed your single quotes in this query:

```
cmdupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE [Current_Account] SET [Amount] = '" & amounttxt.Text.ToString & " WHERE [AccountNo] AND [CustomerName] = " & accnotxt.Text.ToString & " " & nametxt.ToString & ";"
```

Change it to this:

```
cmdupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE [Current_Account] SET [Amount] = " & Val(amounttxt.Text) & " WHERE [AccountNo]= '" & accnotxt.Text & "' AND [CustomerName] = '" & nametxt.Text & "';"
```

I also removed there the single quote from `amounttxt.Text.ToString` assuming it's a value, changed it to `Val(amounttxt.Text)` so that even that textbox is blank, it won't cause an error.

Also corrected your `WHERE` Condition:

Another is you don't need `.ToString` anymore since `.Text` property is already a `String`.